# Check whether link has been shared by friends on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to check whether a URL has already been shared by a user's social network on Facebook?

I have looked at developer.facebook and the graph API reference. I can't see an obvious way to do it, but wondered if anyone had a work around?

Thanks

Comment: `by a user's social network`. I don't get.

Comment: No there is no API for that